# adding numbers in the fstream (C++)

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I can't figure out how to add the numbers in a text file.

> 95 56 34 -56 45 -79

When running the code, the total only shows the value of the first number. How can I add up the numbers in total?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>           
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int numb = 0;
    int avg = 0;
    int total = 0;

    ifstream inputFile;
    int input;

    inputFile.open("numbers.txt");

    while (inputFile >> input)
    {
        cout << input << " ";
        total += input;
        if (input > 0) {
            count++;
        }
        else
            count2++;
    }

    inputFile.close();

    cout << "\nNumber of Positive: " << count << endl;
    cout << "Number of Negative: " << count2 << endl;
    cout << "The total is " << total << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output displays the following:

```
95 56 34 -56 45 -79
Number of Positive: 4
Number of Negative: 2
The total is 95
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Pencil and paper, or a pocket calculator are sometimes good debugging tools.

Comment: total brain fart there... I saw the first digit of the numbers as 95 and didnt even think it would add up to 95. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you add up all the numbers you have shown, the total sum is actually 95:

> 95 + 56 + 34 - 56 + 45 - 79 = 95

I don't see any problem with your code.